# M:N polymorphic relations (e.g. both are polymorphic on both ends)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

I see no ways to solve it in a neat way, that I'd like.

### Summary of the models and relations.

Domain is not exactly the same, but I'm keeping it simpler to avoid distractions.

Imagine you have **three types of users**:

- Admin
- User
- SuperAdmin

System is full of some **other models**, that share same `HasNameInterface`. E.g.

- Product
- Post
- Tag

And every user should be able to "pin" all of that in a single list and, ofc. display that.

Sounds like a polymorphic thing. Let's try.

### Migrations and relations

```php
//...
$table->id();
$table->morphs('user');
$table->morphs('pinnable');
$table->timestamps();
//...
```

```php
class Pinnable extends MorphPivot
{
    public function pin()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class User extends Model
{
    public function pinnables(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Languageable::class, 'languageable');
    }
}
...
```

And this works somewhat, e.g. `User::with('pinnables.pin')->get()` returns user with data I need, but here is what I want.

```
$user->pinned //gives a list of pinned

$user->pinned()->sync([$post->id => ['type' => $post->getMorphType()]]) 
//or even
$user->pinned()->save($post) //or sync(...) this is ideal
```

And all of that WITHOUT messing up with junction table and filling that with my hands. I want to save/preserve laravel magic.

Comment: what is this `HasNameInterface`? Does [the M:N polymorphic relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations) base case not work for you?

Comment: 1. Interface is to avoid questions "why you need collections of different object". Some common interface to avoid overthinking why I need smth like that. 
2. No, cause it contains 1 regural FK and one polymorphic. From what you see, I have a polymorphic from two sides :) Take a look at the migration and compare.